# Adding a button to each item in an array

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-5.0-lollipop

My code records the current Longitude / Latitude and puts in an array and you can view all the history of these recordings in a GPSHistory Activity.

```
        btnGPSHistory = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGPSHistory);
        btnGPSHistory.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(GPSHistory));
            intent.PutStringArrayListExtra("Answer", liGPSAnswer);
            StartActivity(intent);
        };
```

This converts the double to a string and puts in a string and sends it to an array.

```
    async private void GetGPS(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (here == null)
        {
            txtGPSAnswer.Text = "Try Again Later.";
            return;
        }

        dblLongitude = here.Longitude;
        dblLatitude = here.Latitude;

        strLongitude = dblLongitude.ToString("G");
        strLatitude = dblLatitude.ToString("G");

        strGPSAnswer = "Longitude: " + strLongitude + " Latitude: " + strLatitude;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strGPSAnswer))
        {
            txtGPSAnswer.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            txtGPSAnswer.Text = strGPSAnswer;
            liGPSAnswer.Add(strGPSAnswer);
            btnGPSHistory.Enabled = true;
        }                    
    }
```

This is from GPSHistory.cs

```
 namespace GPS2
 {
 [Activity(Label = "@string/GPSHistory")]
 public class GPSHistory : ListActivity
 {
     protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
     {
         base.OnCreate(bundle);

         // Create your application here
         var strLongitude = Intent.Extras.GetStringArrayList("Answer") ?? new string[0];

         this.ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, strLongitude);

    }
}
}
```

The code records the Longitude and Latitude fine and puts in the history page without any problems. My question is how do I attach a button to each of those items in an array that basically tells the program to make those coordinates as "current ones" so that the program can look those coords on the map. Thank you.

Comment: Does the variable `liGPSAnswer ` represents your array?

Comment: @leon yeah it does., I should mention that it's done like this:
`static readonly List<string> liGPSAnswer = new List<string>();`

Comment: Ok, in that case you maybe need an array like this: `List<Dictionary<string, Button>>`, then you can add the string and the corresponding button.

Comment: Its always better to use an async `Task` rather than an async `void`

Comment: I don't know the difference between the two.

Comment: does it work now ?

Answer (score 1):

do you mean you want to add Button to the item of ListView ?if yes,you should use your custom adapter like this:

1.creat you **CustomAdapter** :

```
class CustomAdapter : BaseAdapter, View.IOnClickListener
{

    private Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    List<string> items; //this is the data in my code ,you should replace your own data

    public CustomAdapter(List<string> value) // the parameter use your own data
    {

        //copy your data into the dictionary
        items = new List<string>();
        items = value;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
        {
            dictionary.Add(i, items[i].ToString());
        }
    }

    public override Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return items[position];
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }


    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.item_listview, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txt_location).Text = item;

        var button1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn_set);
        button1.Tag = position;
        button1.SetOnClickListener(this);
        return convertView;
    }

    public override int Count { get; }
    public void OnClick(View v)
    {
        //do the thing you want,location is your strLongitude 
        var location = dictionary[(int) v.Tag];
    }
}
```

}

`item_listview` axml is your custom layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <TextView 
      android:id = "@+id/txt_location"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

   <Button
      android:id = "@+id/btn_set"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Current Ones"
   />
</LinearLayout>
```

2. then in your activity,you could change like this：

```
this.ListAdapter = new CustomAdapter(strLongitude);
```